# the content property does not change with this data trigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a button and I would like to change the text of the button (content property) according to a value of other control.

I am using this code in the axml:

```
<Button Height="23" Name="bntMyButton" Width="75">
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chkTest, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="OK"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>    
                </Style>
</Button>
```

But the button show me the text "System.Windows.Style" and not change. I try to use as value of the condition 0 and 1 instead of true and false, but I get the same result.

which is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have embedded the `Style` as `Button.Content` because you forgot the `Button.Style` markup

```
<Button Height="23" Name="bntMyButton" Width="75">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            ....    
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thaks you very much.